# Docker for windows hcsshim::PrepareLayer - failed failed in Win32: Access is denied. (0x5)

Tags: docker, .net-core

I am trying to build a docker image on docker for windows, always got this error

Docker info:

```
$ docker info
Client:
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Build with BuildKit (Docker Inc., v0.3.1-tp-docker)
  app: Docker Application (Docker Inc., v0.8.0)

Server:
 Containers: 8
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 8
 Images: 13
 Server Version: 19.03.8
 Storage Driver: windowsfilter (windows) lcow (linux)
  Windows:
  LCOW:
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: ics internal l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay private transparent
  Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd gcplogs gelf json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Default Isolation: hyperv
 Kernel Version: 10.0 18363 (18362.1.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202)
 Operating System: Windows 10 Pro Version 1909 (OS Build 18363.476)
 OSType: windows
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 12
 Total Memory: 31.92GiB
 Name: G6CR726W911E
 ID: 363S:P6KR:6TPB:INAE:DGT6:HRT3:QPAK:HZDE:6L5G:4IA3:XNUL:IZST
 Docker Root Dir: D:\ProgramData\Docker
 Debug Mode: true
  File Descriptors: -1
  Goroutines: 27
  System Time: 2020-04-19T21:49:57.0907864+08:00
  EventsListeners: 1
 HTTP Proxy: company proxy placeholder
 HTTPS Proxy: company proxy placeholder
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: true
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
 Product License: Community Engine
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["OktaMvcLogin.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "./OktaMvcLogin.csproj"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "OktaMvcLogin.csproj" -c Release -o /app
```

Output Error:

```
$ docker build --target build -t oktamvclogin .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  6.451MB
Step 1/6 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build
 ---> 7411befde57e
Step 2/6 : WORKDIR /src
 ---> Running in c727ea8e1662
hcsshim::PrepareLayer - failed failed in Win32: Access is denied. (0x5)
```

And this will trigger the company DLP exveption warning which thinks I am transfering data to external driver like USB driver. To do this I have to request an exception to change the group policy. However, the exception only lasts a short time. I have to request an exception again when I build a new image. This is not practical for development.
Can anyone explain why it thinks I am transfer data to external driver when I build docker image? Is there a workaround to bypass this?

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the similar issue. But solved it.

Please go to services in the machine where docker is running and change the LogOn account user from Local Service to your domain user account.

One challenge here, if you restart the docker desktop again, it will set the credential back to Local Service account for docker engine service.

I trying to find the solution for that. Mostly we can set in Docker JSON configuration file.